# Completely uninstall Nodejs, npm and node_modules

Tags: 12.04, nodejs

so my Node and npm settings are currently messed up beyond repair( or so I think). What I would like to do is to completely remove all of it and start from scratch.

What I have done till now can be seen [here](http://achinth.com/post/58262164061/uninstalling-node-js-from-ubuntu).

Output that I get despite removing it:

`node -v`, returns `0.10.33`

`npm -v`, returns `1.4.28`

`which node`, returns `usr/bin/node`,

I have node and nodejs exectuables +links there
I also have a number of npm modules such as jasmine, bower, grunt.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps

1) Open ubuntu softer center
2) Click on installed software
3) Search "node" keyword in search bar
4) Remove all node plugins

Comment: This doesn't work